# Не загружается ubuntu. /dev/sda1 : clean ... file .... block

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При включении ноутбука появляется:
/dev/sda1 : recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean ... file ... blocks
И дальше не грузиться. Что делать?
[image: Экраг]

Comment: для начала, убрать из строки ядра `quite` и , возможно, добавить `nosplash` и посмотреть на чём он на самом деле останавливается...

Comment: По-пробуйте ctrl+alt+f1.

Comment: На какой-нибудь консоль перейти можешь ?

Comment: Версия линукс, проц, видеокарта, материнка какие?

Answer (score 2):

В загрузчике нажмите кнопку `e` и  `quiet splash` сотрите и впишите `noapic nolapic noacpi nomodeset` (*В убунту это можно сделать через меню (вроде F6)* )- должно загрузиться, проверьте драйвера на видеокарту и установленны ли firmware для неё.

Некоторые материские платы с AMD удалось запустить только на ядре 4.19 с параметрами

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"
```